# What is the difference between \nextfen and \pastfen in the package xskak

Tags: chess, chessboard, xskak

I am trying to understand how continuation of a game (to create variations) in chess moves for a particular game can be achieved using

```
\newchessgame
```

along with its options can be done. 
I fail to understand what difference does nextfen and pastfen does when assigned to

```
\xskakget{}
```

command. 
I will add the following code snippet for knowing which part of the code in the manual I fail to understand.

```
\newchessgame[id=A]%
\mainline{1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bb5 a6 4.
Ba4 Nf6 5. O-O}
\newchessgame[
   id=A,moveid=3w,print,
setfen=\xskakget{nextfen},
     %fen after move 3w
id=B,moveid=1b] \mainline{1... Nf6}
\newchessgame[id=C]
\mainline{1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bb5 a6 4.
Ba4 Nf6 5. O-O} \newchessgame[print,
id=C,
% we retrieve the number of the last move
% of game C and set it as first number
% of the new game B at the same time:
    moveid=\xskakgetgame{lastmoveid},
    setfen=\xskakget{pastfen},
id=B] \mainline{5. d3}
```

Comment: don't show only snippets, make a complete example, that makes tests much easier. But beside this:  white plays in your example 3. Bb5, in pastfen of the id 3w the Bishop is on f1, in nextfen on b5.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Got it!